# How to show an expanded silent notification on Android Q

Tags: android, notifications, notification-channel, silent-notification

What I try to achieve is a notification like **#2** ("USB debugging connected"):
shown with title and description on separate lines.

However, when I creata a notification channel with
`NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)` it will be shown as notification **#3** - collapsed with the title on the same line - regardless of the priority of the notification itself (`priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN` or `priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH`)

If the channel importance in increased to `LOW`
`NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)` or above the notification is shown like a normal notification **#1** ("Syncthing is running")

How to show an expanded silent notification?
I also tried setting other options like `setSound(null, null)` etc. but they didn't work either.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mean style of Notification?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
....
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle());
```